# Is finding the area of this rectangle impossible?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

One of my students gave this problem and I am feeling quite ashamed that I could not find an answer. It asks for the area of the pink rectangle and it says that the triangle ABC is a right angle triangle.

I have tried using triangle similarity to find a system of equations, but I could not find a solution.

I would venture that it has infinite solutions, given the informations. But I fell that I am missing something really obvious.

The only assumptions are:

```
AB = 12
EC = 7
ABC is a right angled triangle
The pink shape is a rectangle
```

[image: Find the area of the rectangle]

Comment: Please write the assumptions in the text. We can only see $AB=12,EC=7$, but there is a line above, invisible.

Comment: Without some information to specify the location of the point on AC where the orange point is, this can't be determined. The orange lines are parallel to the sides of the triangle, as the pink is a rectangle, but there's nothing forcing it to be any particular rectangle. It could be a square, or a really tiny sliver near one side.

Comment: The exercise presumes a single answer. Can I conclude it is impossible to find a single real number for the value of the area of the rectangle?

Comment: You need some extra information in order to conclude a definite value. For example, a location of one of the points, or maybe you want to find the largest pink rectangle, etc.

Comment: It seems pretty weird that the point $E$ exists on one side but there is no point $D$. I would assume this is a modified problem from your student, not an authoritative/error-checked textbook question.

Comment: Is there a way to proof that this has more than one answer?

Comment: Pick two different values of $BE$ and check there are at least two answers.

Comment: The problem does have a solution if D is the point on AB. and AD = 12

Comment: @GEdgar, could you please provide a resolution?

Comment: There is not enough information. For example, if the triangle is also isosceles, then the sides of the pink rectangle are 7 and 5, so the area is 35. In the limit $BC\to 7$, then $E$ becomes $B$, and the pink rectangle is degenerated into the $AB$ segment, with 0 area

Comment: user33, students  regularly mis-copy  questions. On this site I often ask for the source of a problem, as a few book pages may reveal what is wrong with the original question posed

Comment: and there is an infinite collection of websites with poorly edited questions  and no errata  listings

Comment: Almost certainly, [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKsoy.png), with $AD=12$ and $CE=7$, is the correct version of the problem (as pointed out by @WW1) and the answer is 84 (as observed in a couple of now-deleted answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area is  $84-49\tan\beta$.

Rotate and reflect the picture to look like this
[image: pic]

Complete $ABC$ to a rectangle $ABCO$.  Let $O$ be the origin
of Cartesian coordinates, let $OA$ be the $x$-axis, let $OC$ be
the $y$-axis.  The dimensions given show that point $E$ is $(7,12)$.
Let $A = (a,0), P = (0,d)$.  The two segments of the diagonal line
have the same slope, that is
$$
\frac{d}{a-7} = \tan\beta = \frac{12-d}{7}
$$
Solve to get
$$
d=12 - 7\tan\beta
$$
The pink area is
$$
(a-7)(12-d) = \frac{d}{\tan\beta}\cdot 7 \tan\beta = 7d = 84 - 49\tan \beta.
$$

Comment: You should add that this means the exact area is not determined by the quantities given. Just from AB and CE the angle \beta cannot be determined.

Comment: Since $\beta$ is written in the picture, maybe we are allowed to use it.  Only the poser of the problem knows for sure...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Suppose $\angle ECF=\alpha$. As can be seen in figure we have:

$AE=\frac{AB}{\tan \alpha}-EC$

$\tan \alpha=\frac{EF}{EC}\Rightarrow EF=\frac {CE}{\tan \alpha}$

area of rectangle is:

$S=[AE=(\frac{AB}{\tan \alpha}-CE)]( EF=CE\times \tan\alpha)=AB\times CE-CE^2\times\tan \alpha$

putting values of AB and CE we get:

$S=84-49\tan \alpha$

In particular case where $BE=2 AB$ we have:

$AE=\sqrt{24^2-12^2}=12\sqrt 3\Rightarrow AC=12\sqrt3+7\approx 27.76$

which gives :

$\tan\alpha=\frac{12}{27.76}\approx 0.4319\rightarrow \alpha\approx 23.36^o$

And area is:

$S=84-49\times 0.4319\approx 62.83$